# How to store multiple username and password in cookies c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

How to store multiple username and passwords in cookies in c#?
I tried But it stores only one username and password.

```
protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (chkRememberMe.Checked)
    {
        Response.Cookies["UserName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
        Response.Cookies["Password"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Cookies["UserName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
        Response.Cookies["Password"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

    }
    Response.Cookies["UserName"].Value = txtUserName.Text.Trim();
    Response.Cookies["Password"].Value = txtPassword.Text.Trim();
}
```

Comment: As per your code, it will only save one username and its corresponding password. What you are actutally trying to do? How from the textbox you will have multiple username and multiple password. In case you application have role based and want the same user access diffrent part or you want other user account access based on permission. Try to implement Impersonalization .

Comment: Cookies are saved per user.  You can only retrieve cookies associated with the user who is currently browsing the site

Comment: Where are you trying to store multiple usernames and passwords? Your code sample only shows one...

Comment: @Thennarasan How to do that??

Comment: Yes it will store only one. That's the logic, why you have to store multiple data inside it in the same machine.

Comment: Is there is any way to store?

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are stored per-user, so your code should work as-is.

I would ***strongly*** recommend that you do not store usernames and passwords in user cookies though due to the security issues associated with this. Use the built-in authentication, which stores a session identifier instead.